# Replace all occurrences of a string (in array) with a single value

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string array:

```
string[] arr2 = { "/", "@", "&" };
```

I have another string (i.e. `strValue`). Is there a clean way to replace all instances of the array contents with a single value (i.e. an underscore)? So before:

```
strValue = "a/ new string, with some@ values&"
```

And after:

```
strValue = "a_ new string, with some_ values_"
```

I considered doing this:

```
strValue = strValue.Replace("/", "_");
strValue = strValue.Replace("@", "_");
strValue = strValue.Replace("&", "_");
```

But my array of characters to replace may become a lot bigger.

Comment: Put the replace in a loop or a method.

Comment: `foreach(string replace in arr2){strValue = strValue.Replace(replace, "_");}`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Was just about to comment almost that exact code, but you beat me to it. Nice.

Comment: *But my array may get allot bigger* - what other items can it include? Will the longer items contain shorter ones?

Comment: `string.Join("_", strValue.Split(arr2))`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `Replace` over and over you could just write your own. This might even be a performance gain since you mentioned

> But my array may get a lot bigger.

```
public string Replace(string original, char replacement, params char[] replaceables)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(original.Length);
    HashSet<char> replaceable = new HashSet<char>(replaceables);
    foreach(Char character in original)
    {
        if (replaceable.Contains(character))
            builder.Append(replacement);
        else
            builder.Append(character);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}

public string Replace(string original, char replacement, string replaceables)
{
    return Replace(original, replacement, replaceables.ToCharArray());
}
```

Can be called like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Replace("a/ new string, with some@ values&", '_', '/', '@', '&'));
Debug.WriteLine(Replace("a/ new string, with some@ values&", '_', new[] { '/', '@', '&' }));
Debug.WriteLine(Replace("a/ new string, with some@ values&", '_', existingArray));
Debug.WriteLine(Replace("a/ new string, with some@ values&", '_',"/@&"));
```

Output:

```
a_ new string, with some_ values_
a_ new string, with some_ values_
a_ new string, with some_ values_
a_ new string, with some_ values_
```

---

As @Sebi pointed out, this would also work as an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Replace(this string original, char replacement, params char[] replaceables)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(original.Length);
        HashSet<Char> replaceable = new HashSet<char>(replaceables);
        foreach (Char character in original)
        {
            if (replaceable.Contains(character))
                builder.Append(replacement);
            else
                builder.Append(character);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static string Replace(this string original, char replacement, string replaceables)
    {
        return Replace(original, replacement, replaceables.ToCharArray());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
"a/ new string, with some@ values&".Replace('_', '/', '@', '&');
existingString.Replace('_', new[] { '/', '@', '&' });
// etc.
```

Comment: Maybe this as extension method would be sexy :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how i'd do it building a regex clause from the list of delimiters and replacing them with an underscore

```
string[] delimiters = { "/", "@", "&" };
string clause = $"[{string.Join("]|[", delimiters)}]";
string strValue = "a/ new string, with some@ values&";
Regex chrsToReplace = new Regex(clause);
string output = chrsToReplace.Replace(strValue, "_");
```

You'll probably want to encapsulate within **if(delimiters.Any())**, else it will crash if the array is empty

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think String Interpolation would work this way.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer why would you say that without trying it out? it works fine for me

Comment: I stand corrected, just tried it, works fine. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: Would this work with `string[] delimiters = { "/", "@", "&", "[", "\\" };`?

Comment: \ wouldn't for sure, the others should be fine within the `[]`. (edit: SO escapting is f**ing up my formatting) "\\" would have to be written as "\\\\" or @"\\" so it gets escaped by c# AND the regex

Comment: @Henrik it would crash horribly indeed :D

Comment: @Henrik You can pass the array of delimiters through `Regex.Escape` if you have any characters with any special significance in regular expressions. `delims = delims.Select(Regex.Escape);`

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Here's one approach:

```
var newString = arr2.Aggregate(strValue, (net, curr) => net.Replace(curr, "_"));
```

If you're only substituting individual characters and have large enough input sizes to need optimization, you can create a set from which to substitute:

```
var substitutions = new HashSet<char>() { '/', '@', '&' };
var strValue = "a/ new string, with some@ values&";
var newString = new string(strValue.Select(c => substitutions.Contains(c) ? '_' : c).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string with your list of string []:

```
string[] arr2 = { "/", "@", "&" };
string strValue = "a/ new string, with some@ values&";
string Output = null;
string[] split = strValue.Split(arr2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var item in split)
{
    Output += item + "_";
}
Console.WriteLine(Output);
//-> a_ new string, with some_ values_
```

---

Updated answer with @aloisdg comment (interesting article, thank you).

```
string[] arr2 = { "/", "@", "&" };
string strValue = "a/ new string, with some@ values&";
string[] split = strValue.Split(arr2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

StringBuilder Output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in split)
{
    Output.Append(item + "_");
}
Console.WriteLine(Output);
//-> a_ new string, with some_ values_
```

Comment: You may want to use StringBuilder ([nice read](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html))

Comment: Interesting! merci :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the fastest but the easiest would be a `Select` with a `Contains`.

Something like this : `source.Select(c => blacklist.Contains(c) ? letter : c)`

Demo on [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N8M4E6).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var strValue = "a/ new string, with some@ values&";

        Console.WriteLine(strValue.Replace("/@&", '_'));
    }
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static string Replace(this string source, string blacklist, char letter) => 
        new string(source.Select(c => blacklist.Contains(c) ? letter : c).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach in a single line to achieve what you want:

```
arr2.ToList().ForEach(x => strValue = strValue.Replace(x, "_"));
```